# How to add a spefici template to buil-in Login system in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I can't find anything about how I can add my personal custom template for my login page to the built-in Login system in django. I've tried to make a login view function to can connect my template with the login system but in this way I can't add login with google and facebook and because of that I can't use that function, but with this classed base view from django I can't handle to add my personal template to this class. Any ideas ?

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Login</title>

  <link href="{% static 'vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="{% static 'css/sb-admin-2.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-12 col-md-9">

        <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
          <div class="card-body p-0">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-block bg-login-image"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="p-5">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Welcome Back!</h1>
                  </div>
                  <form class="user">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Email Address...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Remember Me</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                      Login
                    </a>
                    <hr>
                    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-google btn-user btn-block">
                      <i class="fab fa-google fa-fw"></i> Login with Google
                    </a>
                    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-facebook btn-user btn-block">
                      <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-fw"></i> Login with Facebook
                    </a>
                  </form>
                  <hr>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="small" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password?</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="small" href="{% url 'register' %}">Create an Account!</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>

  <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js' %}"></script>

  <script src="{% static '' %}js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

and the Login class:

```
[
path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
path('login/', is_authenticated(views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html', authentication_form=LoginForm)), name='login'),
]
```

Comment: Are you using Allauth's `/accounts/login/` or your `/login/`?

Comment: /login/ I've changed the login URL in settings.py file

Comment: But you've also decorated that login view with `is_authenticated()`, which can't be correct. (Logging in would only be allowed to users who are logged in.)

Comment: No, that is a personal decorator, I've created that decorator and it gives permision to a user that is not logged in to can log in, the name refers to the users that are logged cannot acces the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the default `LoginView` in your custom view. Allowing you to modify the template.

Like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name="<app_name>/login.html"
```

Comment: Passing it as a kwarg when instantiating the view, like OP does, does the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, but how can I connect the form from html with the class without using a LoginForm but with request.POST['name_of_input'] to can customize the template style and the imputs style as I want ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understant that OP thing ? Can you be more explicit please ?

Comment: It appears the OP wants to handle the requests without using django Forms. Therefore, this would provide an area in which he can handle them manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Allauth and Allauth's views, you can override [those templates](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html) by having a template by the same name (e.g. `account/login.html`, etc; see the source for the Allauth views), in your template directories.

This is powered by [the usual template override mechanism](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/).

The same works for the `django.contrib.auth` templates.

The finicky part is that if you're using [application template loaders](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-an-app-s-template-directory), `allauth` or `django.contrib.auth` must be *after* your apps in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

However, your template can't be used for logging in at present, since:

- `<form class="user">` is missing the correct method (`method="POST"`)
- You're missing the CSRF token tag (so an attempt to POST would fail with a CSRF error)
- The username/password fields are missing `name`s so they're not correctly posted.

I strongly recommend not to hand-code all of your form tags. If you need to wrap things in Bootstrap markup, as you're doing, I recommend e.g. Django-Crispy-Forms or Django-Bootstrap.

Comment: I'm using the allauth for login with google and facebook functionality and on the INSTALLED_APPS they are after my apps.

Comment: If you're using Allauth for google and facebook login, it would make sense to also use it for login and registration.